# Basic code producing TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.x, dogecoin-api

So,  I want this code to have user input Dogechain address, and I get the balance of that address. When I execute this I get error:

```
url = "https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/"+ a
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Code:

```
import requests

def main():
    a = input("Address?")
    url = "https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/"+ a
    response = requests.get(url)
    bal = response.json()[0]["balance"]
    print("Balance:",bal)

main()
```

Comment: `url = "https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/{}".format(a)`

Comment: try this, a = str(input('Addresses?'))

Comment: Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` in Python 2.x. The former does and `eval()` on the inputted string so may return something other that a string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/" + str(a)
```

or

```
url = "https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/{}".format(a)
```

And @Ryan O'Donnell's comment below explains why, thanks.

Comment: This is good but doesn't explain what's happening. OP, the exception is telling you exactly what's up here: you can't concatenate a string and an int. Also latest version of Python allows you to do this: f"This is an int: {some_int}" where some_int is your variable.